# How to expand height of containing view as TextField expands vertically with a newline

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have an array of Views that expand vertically in a scrollView.  The views are of equal width and lined up top to bottom.  Each View has a multiline text field that begins at a fixed height, and gets taller as lines are added.  How can I constrain the height of the parent view to the height of the text field?  Is it possible to do something like this (constraining a view within itself)?

```
Class DocCell: NSView {
    // removed unnecessary components

    var textField: NSTextField!   

    override func updateConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.heightAnchor, constant: 10),
            // ..other constraints
        ])
    }
}
```

The goal is that I don't have to update the height of each view every time the textField adds a new line, and that the size of the containing view just expands with the textField.

Comment: I'm not grasping what the hard part is. Why not just pin the text field's top to the top of its superview and its bottom to the bottom of its superview? If there are multiple text fields, why not just pin bottom to top to bottom to top in a chain down etc.?

Comment: Maybe there isn't a "hard-part" and i'm missing part of how auto-layout works.  My understanding was that if I did that, the textField's height would be static and as newlines were added they'd be invisible.  Will the View increase with the size of the textView if I just constrain it's top and bottom to the textFields top and bottom?

Answer (score 0):

> The goal is that I don't have to update the height of each view every time the textField adds a new line, and that the size of the containing view just expands with the textField.

You have no choice. You need to update the height of the field each time a new line is added. You can, for example, override `textDidChange:` in the NSTextField subclass, and call `invalidateInstrinsicContentSize` (after calling super) and recalculate the size there:

```
override func textDidChange(_ note: Notification) {
    super.textDidChange(note)
    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
    let cell = self.cell as! NSTextFieldCell
    var boundingRect = frame
    boundingRect.size.height = CGFloat.max
    return cell.cellSize(for: boundingRect)
}
```

This will let your other existing constraints do the right thing as long as you have the hugging and compression resistance set to 1000.